# jQuery Form plugin - is there a way to load a page on Ajax success?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When a user uploads a photo, it is uploaded via a controller (profile/upload_picture) that runs validation for filetype, file size, etc.

If validation returns an error, the error is shown via Ajax on the front end. This works.

But if validation returns no errors, I wanted to automatically load another controller/view that allows the user to crop the picture (profile/crop_picture).

Is this possible via Jquery using [malsup's Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started)?

The code below does not work as on success, I remain stuck on the upload page.

Here is my code:

**jQuery in view**

```
$("#file_select").change(function(){

        var options = {
        type:           'post',
        dataType:       'json',
        resetForm:      true,
        beforeSubmit:       function(){
                                $('#loading').show();
                                $('#validation_message').html('');
                        },
        success:            function(data){

                                if (data.success == 0) {
                                    $('#loading').hide();
                                    $('#validation_message').html(data.message).fadeIn();

                                } else {
                                    $('body').load('profile/crop_picture');
                                }
                        }
    };

    $('#upload_form').ajaxSubmit(options);
});
```

**upload_picture controller**

```
function upload_picture()
{
    if ($this->input->post('upload')) {

        $upload = $this->profile_model->upload_picture();

        if ($upload) { // if there are upload errors

            $val['success'] = '0';
            $val['message'] = '<div class="error_message" style="margin:20px 0">' . $upload . '</div>';
            echo '<textarea>' . json_encode($val) . '</textarea>'; 
        } else {

                   //redirecting here seems to have no effect

                }
    }

    $data['selector'] = 'picture';
    $data['records']  = $this->profile_model->get_user_data();

    $string = $this->load->view('account/prf/profile_crop_vw', $data, TRUE);
    $this->template->write('content', $string);
    $this->template->render();
}
```

Comment: can you confirm whether your success callback is run? It sounds like it does run in both cases, since you said you could see error messages when there were validation errors.  So really doesn't it come down to whether "$('body').load('profile/crop_picture');" is working? Can you put an alert before that line to confirm it runs? You can then also add a completed callback to see if your ajax method to crop_picture is working: $('body').load('profile/crop_picture', function(txt, txtStatus) {
  alert('Load was performed: ' + txtStatus);
}

Answer (score 1):

You can try javascript window load function there.
Like this:

```
$("#file_select").change(function(){

   var options = {
      type:          'post',
      dataType:      'json',
      resetForm:     true,
      beforeSubmit:  function() {
                        $('#loading').show();
                        $('#validation_message').html('');
                     },
      success:       function(data) {
                        if (data.success == 0) {
                           $('#loading').hide();
                           $('#validation_message').html(data.message).fadeIn();
                        } else {
                           window.location.href='profile/crop_picture';
                           location.reload();   
                        }
                    }
   };

   $('#upload_form').ajaxSubmit(options);

});
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do a plain redirect to the crop page. I can't see how you handle the uploaded image, but you can always save the image ID or url or whatever you use as the session flashdata variable and use it on the crop page.

Comment: shomz - if I redirect on the controller nothing happens - i think it's b/c the image was originally submitted via ajax and any action on the controller will be passed back via Ajax which is not what we want -- we want a hard redirect (page refresh) and I wonder if that can be done on success

Comment: Then you can rewrite the crop method to be something like: 

    function crop_picture($image_id)...

And you provide the image id from ajax, and then reuse it in the redirect url. Does that make sense?

Comment: btw. I meant you should redirect on the main controller/page, not the ajax one, of course.